# OpenGL ES 2.x compatible with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I am planning to use Ubuntu with QT Creator to study and develop OpenGL ES 2.x applications. it is obvious that OpenGL ES 2.x is not easy to be configured in desktop environment, and OpenGL ES is sub-specification of OpenGL.

So I want to know if it is possible to develop the core part of OpenGL ES 2.x application in OpenGL environment and move my code to android or iOS to develop GUI later?

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to configure? I beg to differ. Just get [an emulator like the one Mali has](http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/tools/opengl-es-2-0-emulator/), and let your program use their libraries instead of system ones directly.

Then you can be pretty sure that the GL code should be fine, as long, of course, as you will manage to run it on iOS(Obj-C++?) or Android(NDK?).

Comment: I am new to OpenGL ES and C++, so it is tricky to me. is there ant document or tutorial to set up OpenGL EL development environment in Ubuntu you can recommend? thanks

Comment: @Korben [The Mali ES Emulator Page](http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/tools/opengl-es-2-0-emulator/) has installation instructions too.

Answer (score 0):

Qt5 is built with OpenGL ES 2.0 by default, so if you use current Qt you will have it out of the box, also Qt developers tell that they will support both android and iPhone in 5.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Mesa implements both regular OpenGL and OpenGL ES: http://www.mesa3d.org/opengles.html.
OpenGL ES 3.0 is supported on select GPUs too, AFAIK.

There's also cross-API compatibility built into most OpenGL libraries, so you can compile and run OpenGL ES code with no or minimal changes. You do need to work out platform specifics like setting up a render context, framebuffers and doing the actual drawing. But this is not GL/GLES specific.

ES API compatibility has been around since OpenGL 3.2 with most calls supported. The remaining ones were added by the [ARB_ES2_compatibility extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/ES2_compatibility.txt), which is part of OpenGL 4.1. OpenGL 4.2 adds full OpenGL ES 3.0 support.

And yes, it works well. I've been running the same ES code on both Android, Linux, Mac OS X and iOS myself. It just needs a little bit more work than single platform support.

Answer (score 0):

I've a own engine which implements ES 2.0 on iOS and Windows, so its working on both systems. You just have to care about unsupported formats and methods ( like pvrtc which is not supported on windows, so i wrote a converter ).

To make it easy i first implement everything on iOS so i know its working, after that i porting it to windows. Currently i've just around 1000 Lines of code which differ on each platform ( But i'm using Xamarin ).